# Spring boot - How to set an Application Property @Value only for a particular class

Tags: spring-boot

We use an application property to enable/disable a functionality.

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "spring.redis.cache.producer.enabled",
        havingValue = "true")
public class MyEntityListener {
     // Omitted 
}
```

But we don't want to activate this in most part of our test base, so we are adding a `TestPropertySource` and try to get rid of it after class using `@DirtiesContext`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.redis.cache.producer.enabled=true", "spring.redis.cache.listener.enabled=true"})
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DirtiesContext
public class AimaCacheControllerTest {
 // Omitted 

}
```

But the Spring Application context is not necessarily restarted after this class, breaking many consequent tests. Since mvn surefire plugin is running the tests in random order, it is not an option  to do `@DirtiesContext(classMode=BEFORE_CLASS)` in the following tests - as we don't know which one that will be.

So the main issue here is to be able to inject an application property and make sure it is reset after the tests are over. How would we achieve that?

I feel like this should be quite common case but I couldn't find any working solution yet.